# in override page_load, additional part should before or after base.OnLoad(e)？

Tags: c#, asp.net

I inherit a basepage and override its method page_load,do sth myself in it,what I want to ask : the method I wrote should before  base.OnLoad(e)  or after it,which is better ? any difference between different location?

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GenerateIEIcon();

        this.GenerateHeader();

        this.GenerateJavascript();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

or

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnLoad(e);

            this.GenerateIEIcon();

            this.GenerateHeader();

            this.GenerateJavascript();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually On Load is called first , so exept if your onload need stuff to be initialize before (localization?) , then you should keep it in the same order , that would be easier to debug and easier to maintain.

Comment: It's a completly stupid answer yaknow look at the page life cycle  [here] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

typically the post as the first instruction to perform load on startup, but this also depends on what you have then run.

Regards.